# python spark simple moving average of fixed number of rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rolling-computation

I am trying to implement SMA (simple moving average) in pyspark.
The problem I am facing is that I need SMA of 3 rows, but spark (in this simple example) gives me SMA 1, SMA 2, SMA 3, SMA 3.

```py
import pyspark # 3.4.1
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 5),
        (2, 10),
        (3, 15),
        (4, 20)
    ],
    ('id1', 'v1')
)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("x")
spark.sql('select avg(v1) over (order by id1 rows between 2 preceding and current row) as v1 from x').collect()
#[Row(v1=5.0), Row(v1=7.5), Row(v1=10.0), Row(v1=15.0)]
```

How can I have NULLs whenever SMA is not SMA 3?

In other words, my expected result is `v1` = `NULL, NULL, 10.0, 15.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use case statement to achieve it

```
spark.sql('''
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id1) <= 2 THEN NULL
            ELSE AVG(v1) OVER (ORDER BY id1 ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        END AS v1
    FROM x
''').collect()
```

Output:

```
[Row(v1=None), Row(v1=None), Row(v1=10.0), Row(v1=15.0)]
```

Comment: thank you, is there any other solution that does not add extra overhead?

Comment: @jangorecki I couldn't think of one that doesn't add extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest slightly other approach with SQL using LAGs:

```
spark.sql('''
SELECT (
       v1 +
       LAG(v1) OVER (order by id1) +
       LAG(v1, 2) OVER (order by id1)
       ) / 3 AS avg_v1
FROM x
''').collect()
```

It may be however a headache to extend SMA window.

Comment: value of 3 is just an simplified example, real window size will be bigger and variable